# Critical points of a map from a complex manifold to itself

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I recently found a problem which I can't understand properly.

> We can think of three dimensional sphere $S^3$ as $\{(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{C}^2\mid |z_1|^2+|z_1|^2=1\}$. Let $f$ be a $C^\infty$ map from $S^3$ to $S^3$ defined by
>
> $f(z_1,z_2)=(z_1^2-|z_2|^2,z_1z_2+\overline{z_1}z_2)$
>
> Find the critical points of $f$.

I haven't read related topics before. But I think this map should be translated into a maps between charts on $S^3$ and find the critical points respectively.

I think if we take $z_1=cos\theta e^{i\phi_1},z_2=sin\theta e^{i\phi_2}$, then $(\theta,\phi_1,\phi_2)$ would be a chart on $S^3$. But then I can't write $f$ in this way.

@Hellen Told me the wirtinger derivatives to solve the problem.

Let $f_1,f_2$ be $z_1^2-|z_2|^2,z_1z_2+\overline{z_1}z_2$ respectively. Then the Jacobson of $f$ should be $\begin{matrix}
     2z_1 & 0 & -\overline{z_2}& -z_2 \\
     0 & \overline{2z_1} & -\overline{z_2}& -z_2 \\
     z_2 & z_2 & z_1+\overline{z_1} & 0\\
     \overline{z_2} & \overline{z_2} & 0 & z_1+\overline{z_1}
\end{matrix}$

Then after some calculations, I found that when $z_1+\overline{z_1}=0$, $(z_1,z_2)$ is a critical point.

Is that sufficient? Anyone could tell me a standard process to solve the problem?

Comment: Or keep it as it is (well, write $|z|^2=z\overline{z}$) and work with $\partial$ and $\overline{\partial}$.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion of the learning of this topics?

Comment: Maybe [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives#Formal_definition) for the definition, then get familiar computing $\partial z$, $\partial \overline{z}$, $\overline{\partial}z$ and $\overline{\partial}\overline{z}$. If you are willing try linearity and the product rule. That should be enough. Later take some complex analysis book. Not sure which one is best, but all you need is the basic computations with them.